# Use ":not" pseudoclass within SASS nesting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to convert some plain CSS to SCSS so I can take advantage of nesting. The code below is an example of where I want to define styles for a bunch of form field input types. In the plain CSS below, I'm setting the default, plus the `:focus` state of the fields. Except for one particular form field (a search field in my global header), where I'm using the `:not` negation pseudo-class selector.

```
input.text, 
input.title, 
input[type=email], 
input[type=password], 
input[type=tel], 
input[type=text], 
select, 
textarea {
    border: 2px solid #c3cbd6;
}

input.text:focus, 
input.title:focus, 
input[type=email]:focus, 
input[type=password]:focus, 
input[type=tel]:focus, 
input[type=text]:not(div.global-search > form > div > input.et_pb_s):focus, 
select:focus, 
textarea:focus {
    border: 2px solid #008ed4;
}
```

And here is my conversion to nested SCSS for the first block:

```
input.text, 
input.title, 
input[type=email], 
input[type=password], 
input[type=tel], 
input[type=text], 
select, 
textarea {
    border: 2px solid #c3cbd6;
    
    &:focus {
        border: 2px solid #008ed4;
    }
}
```

But the second CSS block is trickier to convert to SCSS, because I'm making an exception using the `:not` selector to exclude the search field from having a focus state like all the other forms.

How can I do this in SCSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the SCSS for input[type=text], and write it with the :not selector

```
input.text, 
input.title, 
input[type=email], 
input[type=password], 
input[type=tel], 
select, 
textarea {
    border: 2px solid #c3cbd6;
    
    &:focus {
        border: 2px solid #008ed4;
    }
}

input[type=text] {
 &:not(div.global-search > form > div > input.et_pb_s) {
 &:focus {
        border: 2px solid #008ed4;
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it should work, but I get a parse error: failed on `&(div.global-search > form > div > input.et_pb_s) {` right on the & symbol.

Comment: @user3169905 sorry for that. I shouldn't have separated :not and (div), my fault. I already edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That works! :)

Comment: no worries, glad i can help :)